# CountUp target is null or undefined null React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am getting  this error in react.js , by using the count Up library I have tried all I can, but it still to no avail.

I even used a state to check whether the component is ready for rendering CountUp I don't know whether the error is from the Library itself or from my code. please help me  solve this bug.  here is the code :

```
"use client";
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import CountUp from "react-countup";
import Image from "next/image";
import style from "../styles/about.module.scss";
import me from "../../public/me.png";
import AnimeButton from "./AnimeButton";
import Link from "next/link";

const About = ({ setReferences }) => {
  const boxRef = useRef();

  // State to track whether the component is ready for rendering CountUp
  const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setReferences((prev) => {
      prev[1] = boxRef.current;
      return prev;
    });

    setIsReady(true);
  }, []);
  return (
    <section id={"about"} className={style.about_section} ref={boxRef}>
      {/* heading */}

      <div className={style.particle_animation}></div>
      <h1 className={style.about_heading}> more about me</h1>

      {/* container of the rest of the about section */}

      <div className={style.about_container}>
        {/* details about me */}
        <div className={style.about_details}>
          <p>
            <span>
              Hey, I'm <span>Donkor Pius</span> , a front-end developer
              passionate about crafting captivating online experiences. With a
              creative mind and coding skills, I turn designs into functional
              and visually appealing websites. My focus on responsive design
              ensures seamless browsing across devices. Let's collaborate and
              bring your digital ideas to life.
            </span>
            {/* resume button */}
            <Link style={{ textDecoration: "none" }} href={"#"}>
              <AnimeButton text={"download my resume here"} animeColor={1} />
            </Link>
          </p>
        </div>

        {/* image div */}
        <div className={style.about_image_div}>
          {/* this is the div for the animation */}
          <div className={style.ImageDiv_styler}></div>
          <Image className={style.about_image} src={me} alt="my image" />
        </div>

        {/* other details  */}
        <div className={style.about_other_details}>
          <div className={style.number_count_div}>
            {isReady && (
              <>
                <p>PROJECTS DONE</p>
                <span>
                  <CountUp
                    start={0}
                    end={30}
                    duration={2}
                    enableScrollSpy={true}
                    scrollSpyDelay={100}
                    separator=","
                  />
                  {" +"}
                </span>
              </>
            )}
          </div>
          <div className={style.number_count_div}>
            {isReady && (
              <>
                <p>SATISFIED CLIENTS</p>
                <span>
                  <CountUp
                    start={0}
                    end={10}
                    duration={2}
                    enableScrollSpy={true}
                    scrollSpyDelay={100}
                    separator=","
                  />
                  {" +"}
                </span>
              </>
            )}
          </div>
          <div className={style.number_count_div}>
            {isReady && (
              <>
                <p>YEARS OF EXPERIENCE</p>
                <span>
                  <CountUp
                    start={0}
                    end={3}
                    duration={2}
                    enableScrollSpy={true}
                    scrollSpyDelay={100}
                    separator=","
                  />
                  {" +"}
                </span>
              </>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default About;
```

Comment: Please give the script

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The problem is the **enableScrollSpy** attribute. Although is in the React CountUp docs as a Boolean, if you set that as **true** It'll have the problem finding the target to trigger the transition (I assume, this could be an error).
There's a render prop you can try to solve this: **countUpRef()**; but, I've solved this with **react-intersection-observer** plugin.
How? Well, the attributes **start** and **end** have certain values depending if the inView is true, meaning, that the user is scrolling through the ref. Besides, **enableScrollSpy** is no longer setted. Here's the code:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Row, Col} from "antd";
import CountUp from 'react-countup';
import { useInView } from "react-intersection-observer";

const Example = () => {
  const { ref, inView } = useInView({
    triggerOnce: true,
  });

  return (
   <Row>
    <Col ref={ref}>
      <CountUp
        start={inView ? 500000 : 499999}
        end={inView ? 550000 : 549999}
        separator="."
        duration={3}
        prefix="+"
        scrollSpyOnce
        scrollSpyDelay={800}
      />
    </Col>
   </Row>
  );
};

export default Example;
```

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question while searching for the same error:

> [CountUp] target is null or undefined null

I was looking for a solution that doesn't need an extra third-party package/library.

Thanks to [@Juliette answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77531044/7918037) which points to the error cause (`enableScrollSpy`) and provides a hint for solving the issue using `countUpRef()` I took that and searched for a solution (*without using third-party package/library*) and found that it's pretty easy.

All you have to do is to add `countUpRef` render prop between `CountUp` opening and closing tag. return a `span` with a `ref` prop. that's it!

**bonus:** I saw that you are appending `+` after the countup, you can simply take advantage of the props provided by the library itself, to do so:

- Use `suffix=" +"` to append after the number.
- Use `prefix="+ "` to append before the number.

```
<CountUp
  start={0}
  end={3}
  duration={2}
  enableScrollSpy={true}
  scrollSpyDelay={100}
  separator=","
  suffix=" +"
>
  {({ countUpRef }) => <span ref={countUpRef} />}
</CountUp>
```